# CSS hover tag not working on link

Tags: css

I'm really new to coding and trying to do a very informal website mockup. I'm trying to get a piece of text to reveal itself when the mouse hovers over a link. I know hover is working since the link goes bold as I've directed it to, but I can't get the text to reveal itself.

[this is my html code: I've got two div classes to differentiate what I want seen and hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6Lxn.png)

[this is my css. I know the first .hidden works at the text disappears, but for the life of me I can't get it to show up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mZcD.png)

If anyone has a suggestion that would be great! I've tried to follow very similar code to what everyone else here has posted in suggestion.

[here is the whole html code if that's helpful:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGiZg.png)

Comment: [Please don't use images as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) - copy the code itself into the question, making sure to format it properly `(ctrl+k)`

Comment: You need to use javascript because what you want is an event. And html and css don't allow that. So you must to use the onmouse event in the div tag with the class .hidden

Comment: You do **not** need Javascript for this. 100% don't.

Comment: With the html structure that his has yes. But he can modify the html and obtain the same results, only with html/css

Comment: Well that doesn't make it "need". But I've actually just remembered that you can do it in pure CSS without changing the HTML structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS/HTML is wrong.

`.show-me:hover .hidden {}` will work on the `.hidden` class that it expects to be *inside* `.show-me`. So you hover over `.show-me`, and it shows `.hidden`

Instead, your two divs are siblings of each other. The simplest solution is to put hidden inside of show-me.

```
<div class="show-me">
  <a href="#">Pasta</a>
  <div class="hidden">Vegetarian</div>
</div>
```

### Edit:

Thinking about it, you could use sibling selectors ([JSBin](http://jsbin.com/vafivu/edit?html,css,output)):

```
<div class="show-me"><a href="#">Pasta</a></div>
<div class="hidden">Vegetarian</div>
```

---

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.show-me:hover +.hidden {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: I've put them hidden inside show me, It worked perfectly! Thanks so much, can't believe I didn't see that before.